# Comma Usage in the Name of a Store

Tags: commas

I'm wondering if it's considered okay to omit comma's in the name of my store and on its signage? The name of the store is **Book Bauble and Blessings**. I don't have a comma in my signage or logo's, but when I advertise with my local newspaper, they add a comma to the name. I'd like to complain about it, but not if I'm incorrect in omitting it.

Comment: It's okay. You can punctuate things such as store names any way you like. But your usage of *comma's* & *logo's*  as plurals and *it's* as a possessive is not recommended.

Comment: The question is, do you mean a comma or no? Is it "Book Bauble" and "Blessings" or is it "Book, Bauble and Blessings"? It may not be such a good idea to have a store name with a punctuation (other than an exclamation mark at the end, maybe).

Comment: @Kris The way I understand the question, he never uses a comma in the name of his store, but the newspaper is adding it on their own to the ads.

Comment: Just complain. It's incorrect, not because of any issue of grammaticality. **It's the name of your business -- _you_ control** how it's represented. It's incorrect _because you say it's incorrect_. Go ask this on [Law SE](http://law.stackexchange.com) and they'll tell you the right argument to use if the paper doesn't respond to your request.

Comment: @Spencer That would make the question OT on ELU.

Comment: Names, like lists, need not follow rules but what are you trying to achieve, please? Some kind of trendy innovation, something your potential customers might understand or something that might provoke potential customers to stroll in and ask? Go back a few years and consider the movie Bell, Book and Candlestick. Without the comma, what might that mean?

Comment: Before you start worrying about commas that aren't even there, you should really really start worrying about all the apostrophes you keep sticking everywhere they do not belong. Its. Logos. Commas. Oh my God here comes an S. Focus on the mistakes you're actually making before imagining mistakes you've not made.

Answer (score 1):

Company names are not subject to the normal rules of spelling and grammar, and as the owner of the store you can call it whatever you like. If you deliberately omitted the commas when you chose the name, and you don't like it when the newspaper "corrects" it, you're well within your rights to complain.

I doublt they're deliberately trying to change your name. They're surely used to publishing letters to the editor where they need to correct spelling and grammar, and this is just their normal operating mode. You may need to include a reminder not to fix it up whenever you submit advertising copy.

Comment: See also: my comment at Spencer above.

Comment: @Kris I think it's on-topic because the OP wasn't sure how language rules apply in this situation. I'd be very surprised if it became the subject of any kind of legal action, it's just a misunderstanding.

Comment: Which is why the proposal to migrate to Law SE.